# Imported Flow can't update SharePoint file properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have created a Flow in a Library with my user and tried to export to another user to import.
Both users have the same permission level in the site.

The action to Update file properties does not work in the imported Flow as the one below

[image]

Instead I get an error message "not allowed to reference Runtime API accounts"

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you both have the same Power Automate License? Were the SharePoint connection updated during/after you have imported the zip file? You can first try sharing it with the other user to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The flow is based on the library, if other users has correct permission, he is able to trigger the flow successfully.

Why did you export then import for different user in the same library?

If possible, please provide more information about this issue.

Comment: We are testing the export and import feature. That's why I created the library. Sharing the flow would make invalidate the test.

Comment: Per my test the export and import works well, there will be two flows run on this document library to update the file property